# Configure Read Only Domain Controller to receive config

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain-controller

We have two writable Server 2012 R2 Domaincontroller in our internal network and a Server 2012 R2 RODC in our DMZ.

I don't want to have a connection from the DMZ in our internal network.

I only want one connection from the internal network to the DMZ.

So my question is: Can you tell me how I can configure the writable DCs to push all config to the RODC?

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: What content do you mean? can I ask why you have put an RODC in the DMZ? are there applications that need it?

Comment: sorry, I mean the replication (Active Directory users etc.) Yeah we need that. Some external services need access to our AD database for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think about a few things

1. The ports needed to be open in order for the RODC and Writable DC to talk to each other
2. Securing the communication between your RODC and the writable DC
3. Provisioning the RODC
   and More....

There is a link below to an article on provisioning an RODC in the perimeter / DMZ. Take particular note of the Ports / Firewall and Security sections

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728028(v=ws.10).aspx

Hope this helps,

Mike.

Comment: Thank you Mike! So just to make it clear: the RODC absolutely needs a connection to a writable DC, there is no other option?

Comment: That Is true, you can configure them to use IPSEC so that the communication is secure and that might limit the number the number of ports you need to keep open. if my answer answers question can you please accept it as a correct answer. Thanks.